# Applying a function to a random sample of vector elements

Tags: r

I have been learning R for the past few days, and want to find out whether the problem below can be solved in a better manner (compacter code perhaps) than my solution.

Problem: A vector V of N (~ 1000) numeric elements, needs to be transformed in the following way.

- Choose M (~ 100) elements at random.
- Replace each such element *x* with *f(x)*.

My Solution: `for (i in sample(1:N, M)) V[i] = f(V[i])`

Edit: The function *f* takes as input a single numeric value, and also outputs a single numeric value. Something like: `f <- function (x) x^3 + 2`

Edit: Thanks for everyone's contributions! I now understand the power of vectorized functions. :)

Comment: Hi, can you post the function?

Comment: Added the function definition to the original question.

Comment: thanks, as I thought it is indeed. and you can `f` directly to an entire vector or, like in your case, a part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
   i <- sample(1:N, M)
   V[i] <- f(V[i])
```

No need `for` loop since `[<-` is a vectorized function. See `?"[<-"` to get further details on that.

Comment: This is assuming that `f` is vectorized.

Comment: Thanks, that is a very good solution! I had the table "Summary of subscripting with `[`" from [Rinferno](http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/S/Spoetry/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) in front of me, but the solution didn't flash. Now, I realize how powerful that idea is. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of your function. If `f` is vectorised then

```
V <- f(V)    #  V is a vector with random numbers
```

will do the job. If `f` takes and returns a single value then:

```
V <- sapply(V, f)
```

Thankfully, in `R` most of the function are vectorised, so the first approach would work quite often.

Comment: You can also vectorize your function using `vectorize` for example : using `f <- function(i) rep(3,i);
Vectorize(f)(1:10)` or `Vectorize(f)(V)`

Comment: @agstudy mmm very interesting, thanks. I think it's important to notice that it defines this function wrapper in an environment inside `base`, `> parent.env(environment(f))
<environment: namespace:base>`, so 2 level down the global environment. Which in some case may give you some headache, like could not find the variable :)